# is there a way to trigger an animation of a different gameobject when a different gameobject collides with a different gameobject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

now, I know the title sounds confusing but let me explain my problem. I have some code that makes a gameobject trigger its animation when it collides with a gameobject with a certain name. is there a way to make it so when my PLAYER collides with a game object, it will trigger a specific gameobjects animation without that specific gameopject having to collide? I want a wall to flip up when my player steps on a cube that acts as my pressure plate. Here is my current code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WallFlip : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {


        if (collision.gameObject.name == "FlipPlate")
        {

            GetComponent<Animation>().Play("WallFlip");

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Do something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vj_Ie9i-Ak but play your animation on the door rather than change its position.  There's lots of examples of this sort of thing.

Comment: If you have all the relevant references ... yes why not? Where exactly lies your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would work if you attach it to the player.

```
//SerializeField makes it visible in inspector. This is better than making it public bc of encapsulation
[SerializeField]
private GameObject wallThatWillFlip = null;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collider collider)
{
    //do note that checking for the name will work but is not generally best practice.
    if(collider.gameObject.name == "FlipPlate")
    {
        wallThatWillFlip.GetComponent<Animation>.Play("WallFlip);
    }
}
```

However, I would put a script like this on the "FlipPlate" that would check for the player instead. This would be a bit neater and would allow you to assign different walls to different FlipPlates if you wanted to do that.

Comment: I tried the video, and used my animation instead of vector three, but the animation wont play! (there are no compile errors) ive dragged the grabber into the transform, ive made sure the animation on the grabber is set up correctly and that the name matches the one in the script. what am I doing wrong? here is my code below.

Comment: `using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class triggerGrab : MonoBehaviour
{

    
    [SerializeField]
    GameObject grabber;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {

        grabber.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("grabLift");
    }
}
`